# Pull out ID and Info of my customers (bulk)

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I need to pull out from the table (main data tab) - in bulk (more than one customer ID) - and all the related info associated with their orders:

[image: Table spreadsheet]

For example: Customers 2245, 6987 & 123

The final result I want to be generated should be like the below (see capture):

[image: Result I wish to have]

I have already built up a form that searches all the Customer ID duplicates & responds to all the info - but I have to search for the customer one at a time, with an extensive list that can be a bit time-consuming.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: [ select 1st row > data > filter ] should do.. right?

Comment: I cannot filter the main data spreadsheet as this contains more than 12K records; each time will take ages.

Comment: If you have Office 365, you can use the `FILTER` function.  If you do not, I'd suggest the Advanced Editor and copy to another worksheet.

Comment: I think @RonRosenfeld means Advanced Filter, not editor. This enables you to set up a range of values you want to filter for, then createsa copy of the data on another sheet with the columns you want, in the order you want, for the rows you want.

Comment: FILTER directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the customers to be filtered in the exact order they are listed in the table, as you've highlighted them with different colors. This can be easily done using Power Query. In the example I post there are 3 queries: the first refers to the import of the table in the "Main" worksheet, the second creates the index "as is" so that, in the third and last, the records are listed in the proposed way:

The first query, called 'Table1', retrieved (like the subsequent two) via M code:

```
let
    Font = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Font,{{"ID", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"Color", type text}, {"Nation", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The second query, named 'ID':

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"Color", type text}, {"Nation", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"ID"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

The third,'Result Table', used to populate a new sheet on the Excel front-end, with the desired result:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(ID, {"ID"}, Table1, {"ID"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"ID"}),
    #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Table1", {"ID", "Product", "Color", "Nation", "Quantity"}, {"ID", "Product", "Color", "Nation", "Quantity"})
in
    #"Expanded Table1"
```

So, closing PQ and returning to Excel's front-end, load 'Result Table' into a sheet. This may be done by right-clicking on it's name and choosing "Load to..." and, then, selecting the target worksheet as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new table (not just a range, a "Ctrl+T" table) to hold the list of customers you are interested in, as it feels like this might change each time or at least over time. Give that table a sensible name such as "FilterCustomers".
Use Power Query to pull that table in by selecting any cell in the table then going to Data > From Table or Range.

When you do "Close and Load > Close and Load To" select "Only create connection". Now you have a query that references that table.
Back to your original data range, make that a table too, and load that in Power Query in the same way.

(If this data is in an external file like a CSV that you are loading or pasting at the moment, you might be better off building a solution that pulls in that file directly to remove some steps from your manual process).

Once the data is loaded in Power Query, add a Merge Queries step (equivalent to a database join), associate the ID in your main data with the ID or Customer name in your filter table, select Inner join type and click OK so you will only get the rows from main data that match an entry in your filter list.

[image]

You can add a couple of sorts so you get the final data sorted by customer then product, or however else you might want it. Click "Close and Load" and you have your new table of the data that you want.

You can change the list of customers and refresh the new table (right click > refresh, or Data > Refresh all). New main data? Paste it in, then refresh.